# Does it need to rebuild everytime for new posts? Using gatsby and WordPress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby, headless, headless-cms

I recently creating sample gatsby with WordPress working fine.
Does it require every time to rebuild to gasby when i add new post or blog on WordPress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use webhooks for triggering an automatic rebuild.

Here an example with [netlify](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-to-netlify/):

1. Setup webhook in Netlify

   `Build & Deploy > Continuous Deployment > Build hooks > Add build hook`
2. Go to your WordPress site’s Admin page (

   `Settings > Webhooks > Add webhook`

   - Action: publish_post
   - Fields: ID (this doesn’t matter)
   - URL: paste your Netlify web hook

Note: this will only cause a rebuild of the site Netlify for new posts, you need to create a separate webhook event to trigger for pages. Although if it can wait, until your next post. Gatsby will pull in those changes to posts too.

Credit goes to this [blog post](https://booyaa.wtf/2019/gatsby-wordpress-cutlasses-and-webhooks/).